# Twitter/ general categorisation training corpus

Tags: python, twitter, machine-learning, categorization

Does anyone know of any good broad twitter categorisation corpora?

I am looking for broad categories such as:
 - sport
 - science/technology
 - food
 - health
 - entertainment
 - music
 - games
 - finance
 - education
 - politics
 - television
 - religion
 - motor
 - conflict

(I think that pretty much covers everything)

There are very nice resources linked [here](http://disi.unitn.it/moschitti/corpora.htm), but they are way to specific:

- [Reuters](http://disi.unitn.it/moschitti/corpora/Reuters21578-Apte-90Cat.tar.gz) is specific to commodities and natural resources
- [20Newsgroups](http://disi.unitn.it/moschitti/corpora/20_newsgroups.tar.gz) looks like its for American newspapers
- [Medir](http://disi.unitn.it/moschitti/corpora/ohsumed-first-20000-docs.tar.gz) for cardiovascular medical data

**EDIT**
This is very exciting.  I found this [database](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume5/lewis04a/) via [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/#rcv1-dataset).  Here is the [list of all categories](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume5/lewis04a/a03-expanded-topics-hierarchy/rcv1.topics.hier.expanded).  It looks like it contains what I am looking for.
I'll have to learn how to, and then implement the thing, so I'll have to get back to you guys if it works...

Comment: One way this is accomplished is to find lists of people in those categories and use the Twitter API to read tweets from users in that list. Granted, not all tweets are guaranteed to be focused on that topic, but it will get you one step closer. I would argue that any user who always tweets on the same topic is more than likely a spammer, anyways ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly success!  Though this is not a twitter optimized training data set, but seems to be more for a general text categorisation.
Ok, this was much more awkward than hoped.  First of all,

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_rcv1
rcv1 = fetch_rcv1()
```

creates a dataset that I have no idea how to work with.  The data are 47236 dimensional vectors instead of text tokens with no obvious or documented (that I could find) way on how to deal with that.  So I had to do it the long route.

Looking at the [datasource](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume5/lewis04a/), one can download the token files.  They are broken up into 5 pieces:

```
lyrl2004_tokens_train.dat, 
lyrl2004_tokens_test_pt0.dat, 
lyrl2004_tokens_test_pt1.dat, 
lyrl2004_tokens_test_pt2.dat, 
lyrl2004_tokens_test_pt3.dat,
```

with one file containing all the classifications:

```
rcv1-v2.topics.qrels
```

As a useful side note, for massive files like these, it is useful to just look at a bit of the data to get an idea of what you are working with.  In linux, you can do `head -5 rcv1-v2.topics.qrels` to look at the top 5 rows of the classification data for example.

These files can be linked via an id.  So, I created a dictionary containing all ids with their corresponding text tokens and categorisations.  The reason I did this with a dictionary, which is quite a slow process instead of just creating two lists containing all the values and errors is because I have no idea if the data files match up 100%.

My dictionary looks something like this:
    dTrainingData = {'2286': {lsTokens: [...], lsCats: [...]}}

Then, I create 2 numpy arrays, one for the tokens and one for the categories.  These need to be processed first.  So, you can train the model as such:

```
def categorize(sText):
    import numpy as np
    aTokens = np.array([d['lsTokens'] for d in dTrainingData.values()], str)
    lCats = [d['lsCats'] for d in dTrainingData.values()]

    print("creating binary cats")

    from sklearn import preprocessing
    oBinarizer = preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer()
    aBinaryCats = oBinarizer.fit_transform(lCats)

    from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
    from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

    oClassifier = Pipeline([
        ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
        ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()))])

    print("fitting data to classifier...")
    oClassifier.fit(aTokens, aBinaryCats)

    aText = np.array([sText])

    aPredicted = oClassifier.predict(aText)
    lAllCats = oBinarizer.inverse_transform(aPredicted)
```

The results are mixed.  If you look at the [list of categories](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume5/lewis04a/a03-expanded-topics-hierarchy/rcv1.topics.hier.expanded), you will note that a lot of the categories are financial, instead of a nice even spread that I want.  So I do have a lot of misses.  However, it creates a solid foundation, and using the scaffold highlighted above, it looks easy to just add tokens/category to the `dTrainingData` dictionary for more specific categories.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another, simpler method to do this.  There is a service, called [Meaning Cloud](https://www.meaningcloud.com/), which categorizes the text you send in for you via a very nice API.

Here is a [demo](https://www.meaningcloud.com/developer/text-classification/dev-tools), but to put it in my own words, for python:

```
import requests

sUrl = "http://api.meaningcloud.com/class-1.1"
sKey = #your key - Need to sign up
sText = #your text of type str that you want categorized.
sModel = "IPTC_en"  #or whatever other model you want to use. 

sPayload = "key={}&txt={}&model={}".format(sKey, sText, sModel)
dHeaders = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

oResponse = requests.request("POST", sUrl, data=sPayload, headers=dHeaders)

dResponse = json.loads(oResponse.text)
```

[More info on models](https://www.meaningcloud.com/developer/text-classification/doc/1.1/what-is-model)
You need to sign up to be able to use it, and you can do 2 requests per second, for a maximum of 40k requests per month for free.  For more you need to pay, but I think that is more than fair.

Here is a [nice and visual tree representation](http://show.newscodes.org/index.html?newscodes=subj&lang=en-GB&startTo=Show) of the solution space, and [some general info](https://iptc.org/standards/subject-codes/).  [List of table representation](http://cv.iptc.org/newscodes/subjectcode)